# Does the function $g\in\mathbb{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ exist if...

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Does the function $g\in\mathbb{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ exist if
$\{g > 1\}$ is simply connected and $\{ g > -1 \}$ is not simply connected. I think it does not exist, but I can't find any counterexample of its existence.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ to be defined as $g(x)=-\frac{1}{\|x\|^2+1}$. Then $g^{-1}((1,\infty))=\emptyset$ and $g^{-1}((-1,\infty))=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$.